# Is there a way to auto-populate a cell with a drop-down answer when a new row is added?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to use a google spreadsheet to create an appointment booking tracking system.

When a new row is added in the spreadsheet, the "SHOW" column will auto-populate the cell with the "YES" answer as a dropdown option, if the answer is "YES" it has a weight of 1, if it's "NO", it has a weight of 0. The percentile is calculated based on these weights.

Here's an example:

- [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krqzT.png)
- [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZCKI.png)

The answer can be changed manually as well to either "YES" or "NO" and it should update everytime the percentile accordingly. The script is also supposed to work globally - this sheet will be cloned and the name will be changed - it will also check for eligibility based on two columns: "SHOW" and "SHOW - RATE". This way it will ignore the rest of the sheets.

I have no experience with JavaScript, I did my best to ask the right questions so GPT could generate a script that works.

Here's what I got:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e && e.source) {
    var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var range = e.range;
    var columnName = range.getA1Notation().charAt(0); // Get the column letter
    if ((columnName === "D" || columnName === "E") && editedSheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue() === "SHOW" && editedSheet.getRange(1, 5).getValue() === "SHOW - RATE") {
      var sheets = e.source.getSheets(); // Get all sheets in the document
      for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
        var sheet = sheets[i];
        if (sheet.getSheetName() !== editedSheet.getSheetName()) { // Skip the edited sheet
          var range = sheet.getRange("D:E"); // Assumes "SHOW" and "SHOW - RATE" columns are in columns D and E
          var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(["YES", "NO"], true).build();
          range.setDataValidation(rule);
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log("Event object is undefined or lacks 'source'.");
  }
}
function initializeTracking() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    var range = sheet.getRange("D:E"); // Assumes "SHOW" and "SHOW - RATE" columns are in columns D and E
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(["YES", "NO"], true).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

> The trigger I am using looks like this: Photo:
> [Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4bFe.png) It executes properly
> but there are no changes happening in the spreadsheet. Some help will
> be truly appreciated.

Comment: You have range declared twice

Comment: Why are you looping through every sheet?  Don't you just wish to add this when you insert a row into the current sheet and why are you using onEdit because it won't trigger on inserting a row.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. I want this to work whenever a new row is added but the script should work when the sheet is cloned too, basically I want this script to work globally, in any sheet that has the "SHOW" and "SHOW - RATE" columns.

Comment: Yes, thanks for providing more information because I didn’t understand what you meant by globally.

Comment: Can you also provide an explanation as to what you mean by cloning? If you could limit your terminology to the terminology that we share in the Google app script, documentation, it would be easier to understand you.

Answer (score 1):

Set Datavalidation and Value for onChange trigger and type = INSERT_ROW

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if (e.changeType == "INSERT_ROW") {
    const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    const row = sh.getCurrentCell().getRow();
    const col = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat().reduce((a, h, i) => { a[h] = i + 1; return a; }, {})
    //Logger.log(`sh.getName(): ${sh.getName()},row:${row}`);
    sh.getRange(row, col["SHOW"]).setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(["YES", "NO"]).build()).setValue("YES");
  }
}
```

This function puts the validation rule in the column that has "SHOW" in the header row